# Why “de types” instead of “des types”?

Tags: grammaire

There’s a book named “Recueil de Types de Ponts Pour Routes...”

I’m confused here that, if “types” is in plural form, shouldn’t “des” be used instead of “de”?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Des" is also possible, but with a slightly different meaning :

- *Recueil des types de ponts existant en France.*
- *Recueil des types de ponts que j'ai vus pendant mes vacances.*

One would expect these books to contain all the bridges matching the title.
I interpret *des* in this case as the *de+les* contraction, not the partitive *des*.

*Recueil **de** type de ponts* is more generic. It's just a book containing types of bridges.

One cannot imagine a book simply called : *Recueil des ponts*, without raising the question "lesquels ?"
While a book called simply *Recueil de ponts* seems quite plausible.

In my understanding *Recueil **de** types de ponts* is equivalent to

> compilation of bridge types

while *Recueil **des** types* de pont is equivalent to

> compilation of the bridge types...

Comment: Why don't you think of *des* as partitive here? I think I have a feeling for it, but articles trip me up all the time in French so I want to make sure. Is it because it'd be more natural to express it more like «Recueil de quelques types ...»?

Comment: @wjandrea *De* is a preposition here. It is mandatory after *Recueil*. There is no article before *type* (or there is the *article zéro* if you prefer calling it that way) because you can't write *Recueil **de des** types de ponts* (of some types of bridge). The indefinite plural article disappears by haplology. On the other hand, *De + les* becomes *des* when all the types of bridges are listed.

Comment: @jlliagre So, effectively, it's already a partitive construction?

Comment: @wjandrea The unexpressed *des* is an undefinite article. *L'ouvrage présente **un** type de pont* → *L'ouvrage présente **des** types de ponts* →  *C'est un recueil de [**des**] types de ponts*. Bridges types are countable. *De* is a preposition.