# Is it "Est-ce qu'il y a DE/DES bonnes séries télévisées?"

Tags: grammaire, articles

I saw this question asked with "de" which perplexed me. Should it not be "des"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why “de types” instead of “des types”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/51753/why-de-types-instead-of-des-types)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partitive before adjective?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17872/partitive-before-adjective)

Comment: Both, not really. I want to know the rule or principle, not specific examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when the article is separated from the noun (which occurs often with adjectives that come before the noun), des becomes de. We would say des séries télévisées, but de bonnes séries télévisées.